# How Do I download latest files from S3 Bucket that contains A LOT of files

Tags: amazon-s3, boto, aws-cli

There are a lot of files in my S3 bucket, I am looking to download most 1000 recent ones (uploaded by date).

How do I go on about doing that with AWS cli or s3 boto

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following command:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket <bucket> \
--query 'reverse(sort_by(Contents[].{Key: Key, LastModified: LastModified}, &LastModified))[:1000].[Key]' --output text | \ 
xargs -I {} aws s3 cp s3://<bucket>/{} .
```

I use the following JMESPath functions:

- [sort_by](http://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specification.html#sort-by) : sort the json array, in this case I filter the contents to be only the (Key, LastModified) arguments and will filter on the LastModified attribute
- [reverse](http://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specification.html#reverse) : need to reverse the result as you want the most recent results
- `[:x]`: takes only x arguments of the array, in your case you want 1000 items
- read only the key element with `.[Key]` put as array so we can output as text each element as a new line
- `xargs -I {} aws s3 cp s3://<bucket>/{} .` will copy each of the file found previously from your s3 bucket account locally

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to download the latest element from S3:

```
import boto
conn = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = conn.get_bucket('test-bucket')
bucket_files = bucket.list('subdir/file_2017_')
pointer = [(bucket_file.last_modified, bucket_file) for bucket_file in bucket_files]
key_to_download = sorted(pointer, cmp=lambda x,y: cmp(x[0], y[0]))[-1][1]
key_to_download.get_contents_to_filename('target_filename')
```